# Why to install dependencies of a npm package when npm package gives bundled dist?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install, package.json

I have a npm package let's say my-package and it has some dependencies, dev dependencies, and some peer dependencies and I have published it to npm with dist bundle.
Now my question is if we have a dist of the package then why install my package's dependencies at all? Is there any way to not install it and instead use dist in dev also?